# Wordpress. Get posts without featured image only

Tags: wordpress

I know we can filter posts **with** a featured image by using

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array( 'key' => '_thumbnail_id'), 
)
```

in [`WP_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

But how do I get posts **without** featured image?

Comment: You can use this plugin https://github.com/khanakia/wp-list-missing-featured-images

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this?

```
$args = array(
  'meta_query' => array(
     array(
       'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
       'value' => '?',
       'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
     )
  ),
);
$new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very-very much!

Answer (score 2):

Adding 'value' => '?' doesn't make sense in this context:

In this code, even if 'value' is set, it's actually ignored by WordPress when using 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'. In other words, WordPress doesn't take into account the value provided for the 'value' key when it checks for the existence or non-existence of a meta key.

In conclusion, while this code might work in practice (since 'value' is ignored), my example is more precise and clear. It's better to use my example to avoid any potential confusion.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'post_status'   => array('publish', 'draft', 'pending'),
    'meta_query'    => array(
       array(
         'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
       )
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```